# How to determine the version of MagicalRecord that I'm using

Tags: magicalrecord

I have MagicalRecord installed as part of my project but need to know what version this is.  There must be a simple way, I assumed it would be in the MagicalRecord.h file, or maybe in the CoreData+MagicalRecord.h file, but no joy.

Answer (score 0):

Did you find this in MagicalRecord source code?

```
FOUNDATION_EXPORT double MagicalRecordVersionNumber;
FOUNDATION_EXPORT const unsigned char MagicalRecordVersionString[];
```

Comment: A case-insensitive search of the Magical Record folder hierarchy for the text string "MagicalRecordVersionString" (without the quotation marks) yielded nothing.  In fact, a case-insensitive search for the text string "MagicalRecordVersion" yielded nothing, as did ""MagicalRecordVer".

Comment: cocoapods，using_frameworks!   Perhaps it's necessary!

Answer (score 0):

Changes in the code were introduced in December 2014 to introduce a less [conflicting method of using MagicalRecord with CocoaPods](https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord/issues/934).  If you don't have this code, then you are running a version older than 2.3.0 (including earlier beta versions of the same)

In MagicalRecordInternal.h

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSUInteger, MagicalRecordVersionTag)
{
  /** Version 2.2.0 */
  MagicalRecordVersionTag2_2 = 220,

  /** Version 2.3.0 */
  MagicalRecordVersionTag2_3 = 230,

  /** Version 3.0.0 */
  MagicalRecordVersionTag3_0 = 300
};
```

In MagicalRecordInternal.m

```
+ (MagicalRecordVersionTag) version
{
  return MagicalRecordVersionTag2_3;
}
```